# Jquery CSS with variable?

Tags: jquery, css, variables

I have a Jquery line that adjust the background position of an image:

```
$(".container").css('background-position', '10px 10px' );
```

However I would want this to be dynamic by introducing a variable, but I can't seem to get it right:

```
var backgroundX= 100;

$(".container").css('background-position', ''backgroundX+"px" "10px"'' );
```

Comment: This is just Javascript string concatenation, nothing specific to CSS or jQuery. You need to learn the basics.

Comment: You miss a "+" sign before background variable for string concatenation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In Javascript you connect variables with strings with the `+` sign. You simply add the `variable`, then you write the `+` sign and then the `string`.*

**As you mentioned the correct line without variable is:**

```
$(".container").css('background-position', '10px 10px');
```

**Because your variable is on the start of the string you have to just easily add it before the string and remove the `10` before `px` so that the 10 gets replaced by the variable (which you then both connect with the `+` sign):**

```
$(".container").css('background-position', backgroundX + 'px 10px');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it. Just concatenate backgroundX variable with 'px 10px' string.

```
 $(".container").css('background-position', backgroundX+ "px 10px" );
```

Answer (score 0):

var backgroundX= 100;

$(".container").css("background-position", "'+backgroundX+'px 10px" );